# Javascript Navigator OSCPU Undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, navigator

The navigator's oscpu attribute is throwing undefined on XP IE7 and WIN7 IE9 machines. Other attributes such as `platform` etc work fine.

```
 alert(navigator.oscpu);
```

I want to know how Javascript can identify the version of windows (Windows Xp, 7 or 8)

Can someone help?

**EDIT:**

Got the answer

`navigator.appVersion` return something like this...

4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; MSBrowserIE7; **Windows NT 5.1**; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; dmx:m; mty:p; slx:mi.by.as; ssx:NonCitrix)

So in this

**Windows NT 5.1** means **Windows XP**. 
If it was **Windows NT 6.1** it would mean **Windows 7**
&  If it was **Windows NT 6.2** it would mean **Windows 8** etc.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Read this http://help.dottoro.com/ljlhiaix.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Internet Explorer, use:

```
alert(navigator.cpuClass); // CPU info
alert(navigator.platform); // Operating System
```

It is not part of standards, we shouldn't rely on it.

Reference:

1. http://help.dottoro.com/ljlhiaix.php
2. [window.navigator.oscpu on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.oscpu)

Comment: Thx Shivan. The reason I am not accepting this as answer is because 'navigator.platform' doesnt give us what I want, i.e. how Javascript can identify the version of windows (Windows Xp, 7 or 8).